# Flying an amphibian with ASEL privileges

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, amphibian

So I have an interesting scenario:

You hold an ASEL private pilot certificate in the USA with high-performance and complex endorsements. You also fly a Cessna 206 on a regular basis.

Given that all your certs and currencies are valid, are you allowed to act as the sole PIC of a Cessna 206 amphibian as long as you perform your takeoffs and landings on land only?